# How to get binary output for unique()?

Tags: matlab

`[uniq_elements,uniq_indices]=unique(x)`

shows unique element in e.g. vector `x`.

What would be a simple (i.e. one-liner) and efficient(i.e. fast execution time) way to simply and only indicate 'is this value unique or not' and 'if not' output the first of the series of duplicates? Is there maybe a way to solve this using logical operators? It could be a start to simply have a function outputting 'is this value unique or not'.

example code:

```
x=[5 5 2 2 3 4 4 1 1 1]; %example values
[~,uniq_indices]=unique(x); %returns [1,3,5,6,8]
result=false(size(x));
result(uniq_indices)=1
%console ouput:
result =

  1×10 logical array

   1   0   1   0   1   1   0   1   0   0
```

Basically my presumption is that - because only logical output is needed - the above code could be achieved faster/easier.

Comment: Your code doesn’t mark unique items, it marks the first of each set of duplicates too. I interpret “is unique” differently.

Comment: Why is your existing code not satisfactory? It's pretty rapid in my quick tests...

Comment: @Wolfie: it might be, I was just trying to bounce it off because I had a gutfeeling it could be done better - as stated, it's a personal presumption and could be wrong (in fact, it would be my preference)

Comment: @CrisLuengo honestly, I'm with you on this one. But matlab's unique() function interprets uniqueness differently, that's why I stuck to that in this example. I'd be happy to learn about either 'is unique' or a binary version of matlab's 'unique()' function

Comment: Currently your example only works (by which I mean the logical result array aligns to the input positions) because your input array is sorted. `unique` sorts the result by default... is this desired behaviour? Is the input always already sorted? The answer to this question governs how big of a shortcut you can take...

Comment: it should retain the original indices, it doesn't need to be sorted

Comment: What I'm aiming at is this; `unique` uses a `sort` internally (you can see this by running `edit unique`), and then gets all the positions where neighbouring elements aren't equal. To get the `uniq_indices`, the sort is inverted, and an extra `find` is called (as well as all the internal checks regardless). If you are happy to have a sorted input array, and the corresponding logical array of unique values, you can just do the `sort` and `diff` yourself

Comment: @Wolfie thanks for the explanation, that makes a lot of sense. I think that's (`diff(sort(x))`) good enough! Now I wonder if there's even a theoretical way to determine unique values in a vector without sorting.

Comment: should I delete the question, could this be useful for someone else?

Comment: Note that the output of `diff` is one short of the input, and if you want the logical output not the actual differences then overall you want something like `[true, diff(sort(x)) ~= 0]`. Keep in mind you'll want to store `sort(x)` so that the logical array actually corresponds to something! The question might be useful if it has a useful answer! Feel free to answer it yourself with the best solution you find, so the question can at least be closed. Up to you...

Comment: MATLAB’s `unique` creates an array where all elements are unique. It retrieves one example of each group of identical elements. It does not claim to find the elements that are unique. If you’re looking for either of those options, I don’t know what to aim for. I suggest you decide which one you need. :)

Comment: @CrisLuengo: just the one which outputs the desired vector, thanks for correcting my understanding of the `unique()` function

Comment: why did so many people delete their answers...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Approach 1

This is memory-intensive, as it creates an intermediate `n`×`n` logical matrix, where `n` is the size of `x`:

```
result = sum(triu(bsxfun(@eq, x, x.')))==1;
```

Since R2016b, this can be expressed more succintly as

```
result = sum(triu(x==x.'))==1;
```

#### How it works

`bsxfun(@eq, x, x.')` (or `x==x.'`) creates a square matrix of equality comparisons.

`triu` keeps only the upper triangular part, so that each element is only compared with previous ones or with itself.

`sum` gives the sum of each column. If the sum is `1` this means that the element is not equal to any previous elements, only to itself.

## Approach 2

This is slightly more memory-efficient. It creates an intermediate `m`×`n` logical matrix, where `m` is the number of unique elements and `n` is the total number of elements:

```
xu = unique(x);
result = any(diff([false(numel(xu),1) bsxfun(@eq, x, xu.')],[],2)==1);
```

Since R2016b, the second line can be replaced by

```
result = any(diff([false(numel(xu),1) x==xu.'],[],2)==1);
```

#### How it works

This creates a matrix, say `A`, of comparisons of each unique element of `x` (row index of `A`) with each element of `x` (column index of `A`). Let `B` denote the result of appending a column of `false` to `A`.

An element that appears in `x` for the first time corresponds to a `[0 1]` subsequence in the corresponding row of `B`. To detect this, `diff` is applied along each row, and the result is compared with `1` (which is the increment between the elements in `[0 1]`).

Comment: it may be more memory intensive but it also runs about 1.5-1.75x faster than my code using tic toc on my machine. And it's codegasmic! Can you explain the logic of using `triu()`?

Comment: @user2305193 I added an explanation, and another method

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks! It's actually not needed, and removing it increases speed

Comment: I tested the first approach for larger vectors, it appears to become more efficient the larger the vector

Comment: @user2305193 It should be fast as long as there is enough memory. But for very large vectors memory will be the limiting factor

Comment: BTW, did you compare to Suever’s idea using `histc` (in the deleted answer)? That one is more memory efficient, I wonder what it is for speed?

Comment: @CrisLuengo I took a quick look at his answer, but since `histc` is deprecated and I don't like how `histcounts` requires and extra `inf` to achieve the same result, I didn't follow that route :-)

Comment: didn't, would if it were still available!